# How to display the button based on value(0/ 1) in the DOM using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 cards with 2 buttons `ON` and `OFF` each.

HTML:

```
<div class = "card" id ="b1" value = 0>
     <button class = "on" > ON </button>
     <button class = "off"> OFF </button>
</div>

<div class ="card" id ="b2" value = 1>
    <button class = "on" > ON </button>
    <button class = "off"> OFF </button>
</div>

<div class ="card" id ="b3" value = 1>
    <button class = "on" > ON </button>
    <button class = "off"> OFF </button>
</div>
```

If `value =1`, **ON** button should be displayed. If `Value =0`, then **OFF** button should be displayed based on the value from the DOM.

I used the below **JS code**:

```
var card = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
  var target = card[i].id;
  var cardId = document.getElementById(target);
  var val = $(cardId).attr("value");
  if (val== 0) 
  {
    $(".off").show();
    $(".on").hide();
  } 
  else
  {
    $(".off").hide();
    $(".on").show();
  }
}
```

But, I need to get `OFF`, `ON` and `ON` button to  be displayed in 3 cards, Since `value is 0` in the first card, So `OFF`. `Value :1` in card2 and card 3 , So `On` button should be displayed.

But, I get all the 3 cards with `On` button.

I am not sure what is wrong with my JS code.

Could someone please help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use CSS:

```css
*. ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.card {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

/* select a button with the class of 'on',
   which is a descendant of a <div> element
   with the class of 'card' and a 'value'
   attribute equal to "0", and hiding it: */
div.card[value="0"] button.on {
  display: none;
}


/* select a button with the class of 'off',
   which is a descendant of a <div> element
   with the class of 'card' and a 'value'
   attribute equal to "0", and showing it: */
div.card[value="0"] button.off {
  display: block;
}

/* select a button with the class of 'on',
   which is a descendant of a <div> element
   with the class of 'card' and a 'value'
   attribute equal to "1", and showing it: */
div.card[value="1"] button.on {
  display: block;
}

/* select a button with the class of 'off',
   which is a descendant of a <div> element
   with the class of 'card' and a 'value'
   attribute equal to "1", and hiding it: */
div.card[value="1"] button.off {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="b1" value=0>
  <button class="on"> ON </button>
  <button class="off"> OFF </button>
</div>

<div class="card" id="b2" value=1>
  <button class="on"> ON </button>
  <button class="off"> OFF </button>
</div>

<div class="card" id="b3" value=1>
  <button class="on"> ON </button>
  <button class="off"> OFF </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you support . Really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you select `.off` or `.on` without restrict the scope, all of elements with these classes in `Document` are affected.
You can use this in `jQuery`:

```js
$(".card").each(function(){
  if( parseInt( $(this).attr("value") ) == 0 )
  {
    $(this).find(".off").show();
    $(this).find(".on").hide();
  } else
  {
    $(this).find(".off").hide();
    $(this).find(".on").show();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "card" id ="b1" value = 0>
     <button class = "on" > ON </button>
     <button class = "off"> OFF </button>
</div>

<div class ="card" id ="b2" value = 1>
    <button class = "on" > ON </button>
    <button class = "off"> OFF </button>
</div>

<div class ="card" id ="b3" value = 1>
    <button class = "on" > ON </button>
    <button class = "off"> OFF </button>
</div>
```

By your code that's enough use:

```
if (val== 0) 
{
     $(cardId).find(".off").show();
     $(cardId).find(".on").hide();
} 
 else
{
    $(cardId).find(".off").hide();
    $(cardId).find(".on").show();
}
```

instead of

```
   if (val== 0) 
  {
    $(".off").show();
    $(".on").hide();
  } 
  else
  {
    $(".off").hide();
    $(".on").show();
  }
```

Comment: you mean,  $(cardId).find(".off").hide() or .show();
$(cardId).find(".on").show() or .hide(); . This too works ?

Comment: No, I wrote like this to summarize, it must be written separately. Use `$(cardId).find(".off").hide()`  or `$(cardId).find(".off").show()`  Wherever you needed

Comment: I edited answer and write the last part more clearly

Comment: Yes, understood. Thank you so much for explaining. It helps a lot.

Comment: you're welcome. I'm glad you found it useful

Comment: I need a help, If one button  in the card has OFF ( all the controls Play, Pause and Delete) will be Disabled. If two buttons in the other cards have ON( all the controls except PAuse will be Enabled). If we click Play button, Pause should be Enabled and Play and Delete should be disabled. If we press the pause button, Play and delete should be Enabled, Pause should be disabled. The Problem is, Since there is ON button for both the cards,  clicking a Play button in card2, Pause button gets Enabled in card3. Here is the codepen "https://codepen.io/DarKV/pen/BaRXvLm". Could you help pls?

Comment: Hi, Please ask a new question under a new topic to make the answer clearer

Answer (score 0):

I fix your code by adding the container id (name target on js file) and the class name (on or off), because if you set only the class name, all the buttons will take the last card value.

I hope this answer helps you with your problem

```js
var card = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
  var target = card[i].id;
  var cardId = document.getElementById(target);
  var val = parseInt($(cardId).attr("value"));
  
  if (val == 0){
    $("#"+target+" .off").css('display','block');
    $("#"+target+" .on").css('display','none');
  }else{
    $("#"+target+" .off").css('display','none');
    $("#"+target+" .on").css('display','block');
  }
}
```

```css
.card{
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "card" id ="b1" value = 0>
     <button class = "on" > ON </button>
     <button class = "off"> OFF </button>
</div>

<div class ="card" id ="b2" value = 1>
    <button class = "on" > ON </button>
    <button class = "off"> OFF </button>
</div>

<div class ="card" id ="b3" value = 1>
    <button class = "on" > ON </button>
    <button class = "off"> OFF </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create with js

```js
const cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

for (card of cards) {
  const is_on = card.getAttribute("value");
  const buttonOn = card.getElementsByClassName('on')[0]
  const buttonOf = card.getElementsByClassName('off')[0]
  if (Number(is_on) === 1) {
    buttonOf.style.display = 'none'
    buttonOn.style.display = 'inline-block'
  } else {
    buttonOf.style.display = 'inline-block'
    buttonOn.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="b1" value=0>
  <button class="on"> ON </button>
  <button class="off"> OFF </button>
</div>

<div class="card" id="b2" value=1>
  <button class="on"> ON </button>
  <button class="off"> OFF </button>
</div>

<div class="card" id="b3" value=1>
  <button class="on"> ON </button>
  <button class="off"> OFF </button>
</div>
```